# Error in loading model in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I Have the following code snippet

```
from train import predict
import random
import torch


ann=torch.load('ann.pt') #importing trained model


while True:
      k=raw_input("User:")
      intent,top_value,top_index = predict(str(k),ann)
      print(intent)
```

when I run the script it is throwing the error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    ann=torch.load('ann.pt') #importing trained model
  File "/home/local/ZOHOCORP/raghav-5305/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 261, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
  File "/home/local/ZOHOCORP/raghav-5305/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 409, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ANN'
```

I have **ann.pt** file in the same folder as my script is.
Kindly help me identify fix the error and load the model.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to save both parameters and model, pytorch pickles the parameters but only store path the model Class. For instance, changing tree structure or refactoring can break loading. 
Therefore as the [documentation points out](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/761d6799beb3afa03657a71776412a2171ee7533/docs/source/notes/serialization.rst), it is not recommended, prefer only save/load parameters:

> ...the serialized data is bound to the specific classes and the exact directory structure used, so it can break in various ways when used in other projects, or after some serious refactors.

For more help, it'll be useful to show your saving code.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to construct the ANN class from which the ann.pt file was created and then call class.load_state_dict() with ann.pt